# How to make a thread run periodically for computing game movement?

Tags: android, multithreading, loops

I've been building a game for some time, and just realized I did something very wrong the whole time, and still don't really know better.

I have a control class, my `MainActivity`, which pretty much only does the following:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    operator=new Operator(getBaseContext());
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); //<- framelayout with the view and two buttons on top
}
//Buttons:
public void shoot(View view) {
    operator.shoot(view.getId());
}

public void pause(View view) {
    AndronXView.running=!AndronXView.running;
}
```

Then there is my `View`, which draws Actors and makes my workerthread compute everything:

```
public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    animHandler = new Handler();
    animHandler.postDelayed(loadLvl1, 5000);
    arrayOfActors = operator.getActors(); //simplyfied to one array
    if(arrayOfActors==null)
        arrayOfActors=new Actor[0]; //if op hasn't loaded yet, prevent NPE in onDraw
    //stripped of unimportant color and size computing stuff
}

protected void onDraw(final Canvas canvas){

    //Should I copy player before doing this? Never got problems here so far.
    canvas.drawBitmap(operator.player.getCurrentGraphic(), operator.player.getX(), operator.player.getY(), null);

    for(Actor actor:arrayOfActors) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(actor.getCurrentGraphic(), actor.getX(), actor.getY(), null);
    }

    if (running) {
        operator.run();   //Compute. Realized my mistake here and changed the inside, wait for it.
        animHandler.postDelayed(r, Operator.FRAME_RATE);    //r=invalidate();
        animHandler.post(loadActors);                      //get Arrays from op
    }else animHandler.post(wait);
}

Runnable wait = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (running)
            animHandler.post(r);
        else animHandler.postDelayed(this, Operator.FRAME_RATE);
    }
};
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(@NonNull MotionEvent event){
    int action = event.getAction();

    if(action==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN || action==MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
        operator.player.setSpeed((event.getX()-operator.player.getHorizontalMid())
                        /AndronX.PLAYER_MOVE_LAG,
                (event.getY()-operator.player.getVerticalMid())/AndronX.PLAYER_MOVE_LAG);
    }
    return true;
}
```

And then there is my `Operator`, extending `Thread`, which computes movement and interactions of the actors in the background:

```
public Operator(Context baseContext) {
    this.player = new Player(baseContext); //context to load drawable from ressource
    arrayListOfActors=new ArrayList<>();
    //Looper.prepare(); //it crashed and said only one Looper/Thread
    //Looper.loop();    //so I removed it
    opHandler = new Handler();
}
@Override
public void run() {
        opHandler.post(gameStep); //before, I had the whole processing inside this run().
}

private Runnable gameStep = new Runnable(){
    player.move();
    computeEveryMemberOf(arrayListOfActors); //much computing happens here, usually 
//contains 1-30 Actors that get cross-referenced
    arrayOfActors = arrayListOfActors.toArray(new Actor[arrayListOfActors.size()]);
}

public Actor[] getActors(){
    return arrayOfActors;
}
```

Before, I had the computign directly in my operators run() method, which I realized made the background thread useless. I#m not sure though if this is the right way, should I let the operator loop itself, would the two threads kinda stay in sync? Does it even matter?

Or should I go `run(){ sleep(FRAME_RATE); compute();}`?

Edit: A big problem arose, and I'm not sure if it's because of this, so I really need an answer here how to do this the right way.

With every step, I move some actors a little bit up or down, in a cosinus wave like speed (like it's projection to an axis), and currently, the actual movement doesn't get through to the view, they just jump from max to min and back, although they do it in the desired speed(looks like extreme lag).

Actually you can see for yourself what this problem is:  https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/28278772/AndronX.apk

Comment: You need to use synchronization primitives if you want two threads to stay in sync. Use Java-builtin `synchronized`.

Comment: Staying in sync is only my second priority at the moment, I'm looking for the right way to actually keep the background thread running first :) e.g. if i do it like it is now, there is no need for explicit syncing.